# Azure App Service Containers where are named volumes stored?

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service, docker-volume

I am trying to host a CalDAV server (Baikal) with MySQL backend - but the issue isn't related to these images specifically. My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this

```yaml
version: "3.4"
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: kU47k9PpjU5A
      MYSQL_DATABASE: baikal
      MYSQL_USER: baikal
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: PY74bSs72fkT
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql

  baikal:
    image: ckulka/baikal:nginx
    container_name: baikal
    restart: always
    ports:
    # These ports are in format <host-port>:<container-port>
      - 80:80

    volumes:
      - baikal_specific:/var/www/baikal/Specific
      - baikal_config:/var/www/baikal/config

volumes:
    db_data:
    baikal_specific:
    baikal_config:
```

I have used named volumes and set the `WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE` setting to `true`. This works flawlessly and I am able to store and persist data between app restarts.

But I am unable to find where exactly are the volumes stored on the file system (I search via bash shell in Kudu). I looked around everywhere (even outside the /home directory) but couldn't find them. I cannot run `docker volume ls` as docker client is not available in kudu.

I don't feel comfortable running containers on azure app service not knowing where the data is **actually** stored as I might have to take a backup of the files if I decide to host containers somewhere else.

I am using a free app service plan which comes with 1GB of storage and thus would like to utilize this instead of mounting azure file shares. Also, I am aware of `WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME` but don't want to use local paths as there are other issues with it which I've asked here - [StackOverflow - Azure App Service multi containers volume not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77494437/azure-app-service-multi-containers-volume-not-working).

Answer (score 0):

When you use Docker containers, the storage for volumes is managed by Azure Storage. The data is not stored directly on the file system of the underlying virtual machine, and you won't be able to access it directly from Kudu or the Docker command line within the App Service environment.

- Containers might face challenges accessing persistent local files, especially when the app service restarts.

##### Possible Solutions:

- Instead of directly mapping to `${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}`, consider using Docker volumes. They are more flexible and can handle storage across container restarts.
- Docker Compose only ensures that the MySQL container starts before Baikal. It doesn't guarantee that the MySQL server is fully initialized and ready to accept connections.

```yaml
# Inside the "baikal" service definition
command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "mysqldb:3306", "--", "your_actual_startup_command"]
```

Consider using a tool like `wait-for-it` or `dockerize` in the Baikal container's startup script to wait until the MySQL server is ready to accept connections.

**wait-for-it.sh:**

```
set -e

hostport=$1
shift
cmd="$@"

# Default values
timeout=15
use_ssl=0

# Parse command line options
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    case "$1" in
        *:* )
            hostport=$1
            ;;
        -t )
            timeout=$2
            shift
            ;;
        -s )
            use_ssl=1
            ;;
        -- )
            shift
            cmd="$@"
            break
            ;;
        * )
            echo "Invalid argument: $1"
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done

host=$(echo "$hostport" | cut -d: -f1)
port=$(echo "$hostport" | cut -d: -f2)

echo "Waiting for $host:$port to be ready..."

if [ "$use_ssl" -eq 1 ]; then
    scheme="https://"
else
    scheme="http://"
fi

timeout_cmd="timeout $timeout"

until $(curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail "$scheme$host:$port"); do
    echo "Still waiting for $host:$port..."
    sleep 1
    $timeout_cmd 1 true || break
done

echo "$host:$port is available! Executing command: $cmd"
exec $cmd
```

Comment: I don't have any active Azure Storage Account in my subscription - so I have not idea where azure is storing the named volumes. In official docs, they recommend using `${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}` to store persistent files (no examples given for named volumes). But since named volumes are working in app service, I wanted to know where they are actually stored. I understand that container startup times may be different (Baikal may start before MySQL), but that isn't my question here.

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself incase if someone also has the same question

I noticed that If I kept the apps service running (& didn't let let sleep) I was able to persist data using named volumes.

But after coming back after a couple of days and accessing the web-app, the data was no longer available. This means that that volumes are stored in the host machine **currently** assigned to/running the app. This volume is not accessible via Kudu or by any other means.

If Azure decides to move the app to another machine (which obviously wont have the volume), then the data would be lost. A new host machine is assigned to the app service when we stop the app service for an elongated period of time & start it back again. Also in my case, especially on F1 App Service Plans where the app service shuts down the app after some period of inactivity.

However, I would still recommend using named volumes (if for some reason bind local path using `WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME` doesn't work for you) for (bursty) workloads that can sustain data loss.